# Why does this bash loop only output the last 3 lines?

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop, cat, fastq

I am trying to write a bash script that takes a text file wherein each line is a number, and loop through each line, searching all the files in all directories for a file name that contains that number. The output should be the absolute path so that I know where to look to get the file.
For example, the first line of my text file is "286." I want to find every file that contains "286" in the file name and have the computer tell me what directory contains it.

So far I have:

```
for num in $(cat StockTest.txt); do find ./ -name "*$num*.fastq.gz" -print; echo $num; done
```

The output looks like:

```
286
297
300
303
315
531
540
607
613
616
619
637
655
664
681
687
690
./ERS/OldSwabMATCHES/GP_692_A_S298_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
./ERS/OldSwabMATCHES/GP_692_A_S298_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
692
./BASHPROJECT/UvS_Combined_030714/UvS-696-A_S10_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
./BASHPROJECT/UvS_Combined_030714/UvS-696-A_S10_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
696
./BASHPROJECT/UvS_Combined_032114/UvS-718-B_S42_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
./BASHPROJECT/UvS_Combined_032114/UvS-718-B_S42_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
718
```

As you can see, the echo for each number worked, but it only found the locations for the last three files. However, if I run the exact find command but with each of these numbers on their own, outside of the loop, it returns locations.

ie. `find ./ -name "*286*.fastq.gz" -print`
returns

```
./ERS/OldSwabMATCHES/GP_286_A_S444_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
./ERS/OldSwabMATCHES/GP_286_A_S444_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

Why would it only do the find command on three of the last lines of the file instead of all of them?

I have also tried this using a while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; find -name "*-$line-*.fastq.gz" -print; done < "StockTest.txt"
```

and I get the exact same output.
Thank you!!!

Comment: I'll bet there are carriage return characters in the file. Use `dos2unix StockTest.txt` to clean it.

Comment: The other issue is if the file has, say 1k lines. Then `find` would run 1k times too.

Comment: assuming `StockTest.txt` isn't too big (20 lines?), take a look at the output from `od -c StockTest.txt` ... you're looking for any non-printing characters that could be causing problems; `\n` is ok, `\r` (windows carriage return could be problematic - run `dos2unix StockTest.txt` to remove `\r`); if in doubt then update question with output from the `od -c ...` call; if `StockTest.txt` is really big then cut it down to a smallish file (eg, 20 lines which still shows the unwanted behavior) and run through `od -c ...`

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes `find` is the best answer.
Sometimes maybe it is not.

Try it with tweaked globbing.

```
shopt -s globstar
printf "%s\n" ./**/*.fastq.gz | grep -f StockTest.txt
```

You can add pattern refinements in the file, too.
Make sure there are no carriage returns, as already mentioned.

Comment: Actually your approach would work with `find` as well. You could use `find` instead of `**` to produce the list of gz files on stdout. It would be interesting to test, which version is faster.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't compare. I just like to show alternative options. :)